# org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'

Tags: java, spring, mockito, junit4

I have developed one spring sample project with a controller and called a static method in it.

When I try to run the code, it leads me to an exception.

**LoginController .java**

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/login")
public String login(){
    System.out.println("in login method");
    String s = SampleClass.method();
    System.out.println("String value :  "+s);
    return "welcome to login page";
}}
```

**SampleClass.java**

```
public class SampleClass {

public static String method(){
    System.out.println("in static method");
    return "static method";
}}
```

**LoginControllerTest.java**

```
@PrepareForTest(SampleClass.class)
public class LoginControllerTest {

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@InjectMocks
private LoginController loginController;


@Before
public void setUp() {

    System.out.println("in setup");
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(SampleClass.class);

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(loginController).build();
    System.out.println("setupdone");

}

@Test
public void loginTest() throws Exception{
    System.out.println("in login test");
    PowerMockito.when(SampleClass.method()).thenReturn("hello");
    mockMvc.perform(get("/login"))
    //.andDo(print())
    .andExpect(status().isOk());
    System.out.println("test completed");
}}
```

**Error**

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
>   when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
>   For example:
>       when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);
>
> Also, this error might show up because:
>   1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.    Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.    Mocking methods
>   declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
>   2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
>
> at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when(PowerMockito.java:495)
>     at
>   com.junit.example.controller.LoginControllerTest.setUp(LoginControllerTest.java:57)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

Can any one help me out with a solution?

Answer (score 4):

Based on the docs, you're not using this correctly:
https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage

From the docs:

1. Annotate the class with `@PrepareForTest(Static.class)` ***(You're not doing this)***
2. Call mockStatic `PowerMockito.mockStatic(Static.class);`
3. Use `Mockito.when()`. You are using `PowerMockito.when()`

Comment: He is doing the `PrepareForTest` call and `PowerMockito.when` with one argument is just a forward to `Mockito.when`, as `PowerMockito` adds some overloads and you would not be able to statically import `when` from both classes unless you use Groovy, so the question remains, where is the problem.

Comment: This answer's over two years old now, so I don't remember this at all. I could have made a mistake here, but it's strange that I would have missed this _and_ gotten two upvotes. The edit history doesn't show that PrepareForTest was ever missing.

Comment: That's not strange at all. You describe valid possible problems. At least two users have the error you describe and thus upvoted your answer. But this does not mean it has any relevance for the OP, especially as the answer was not accepted. In the current state it is not really helpful for the actual question.

Answer (score -2):

Why are you making your Test complicated?, when you can simply write it as:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

import com.arpit.controller.LoginController;

public class LoginControllerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private LoginController loginController;

    @Before
    public void setupMock() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void loginTest() {
        String val = loginController.login();
        assertEquals("welcome to login page", val);
    }
}
```

**Output on Console:**

```
in login method
in static method
String value :  static method
```

Comment: PowerMock is used when you are trying to mock static methods. The original question is trying to mock SampleClass.method() called from static context. This is why the test is structured that way.